# I get connection warning (Local instance MYSQL80) Whenever I use sqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, connection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNRkj.png)

I get the connection warning "Incompatible/non standard server version or connection protocol detected (8.2.0)" in SQL. Is there anyway to fix this warning? And what is the cause of this issue?

I tried to check if I used an outdated version of SQL workbench, but I believe im using the latest one 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Click the checkbox, "don't show this message again" if you don't want to see the message.

MySQL Workbench seems to have minimal developer attention. It has bugs that have languished in an open state for years. So it's no surprise that it hasn't been tested with MySQL 8.2, which was released 2023-10-25 — less than one month ago, as we write this.

I have no idea what features of MySQL Workbench, if any, will be incompatible with MySQL Server 8.2. That's the point — the makers don't know either, because they haven't completed testing and certification.

There are definitely some features that have changed in MySQL 8.2, and 8.1 as well. You should read both of these pages carefully if you use MySQL 8.2:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/mysql-nutshell.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/mysql-nutshell-8-1.html

To be honest, I don't use MySQL Workbench. I use command-line interfaces. The GUI doesn't do anything for me that I can't do with the CLI tools, and I can script the CLI tools.